# RadioButton Intent activity - android

Tags: java, android, radio-button

Hej!
I would really appreciate some help. I have already researched forums but cant seem to find a solution. I want to move to another activity (page) when a radio button is checked and I click submit. If another RadioButton is checked, then I want to move to another activity-page. I am stuck and I just cant find a way out.

XML:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.dietchallenge.second">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/write_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"/>



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/vegan" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/vege"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/gluten"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/all"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/summary1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/question1_submit"
            android:onClick="enter"/>

</LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

```html
package com.example.android.dietchallenge;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class second extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView myMessage;
    TextView summary;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        String message = getIntent().getStringExtra("message_key");
        myMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.write_name);
        myMessage.setText("Hello " + message + "!");

        summary = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.summary);
        summary.setText("Let's start by figuering out what you like. This is your first question." + "\n" + "Which is your favourite diet?");


        }


    public void enter(View view) {

        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.radio1:
                if (checked) {
                    Intent page = new Intent(second.this, three.class);
                    startActivity(page);}
                // Pirates are the best
                break;
            case R.id.radio2:
                if (checked)
                {
                    Intent page = new Intent(second.this, four.class);
                    startActivity(page);}
                // Ninjas rule
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38994546/7427111

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/, can change activity on Display button as Submit(in your case).

Answer (score 0):

You have not added click listener on `Button`.

you can do following:

Inside your `onCreate()` add click listener on button like this.

```
findViewById(R.id.summary1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        RadioButton veganRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        RadioButton vegeRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);

        if(veganRadioButton.isChecked()) {
            Intent page = new Intent(second.this, three.class);
            startActivity(page);
        } else if(vegeRadioButton.isChecked()) {
            Intent page = new Intent(second.this, four.class);
            startActivity(page);
        } else {
            //neither radio1 nor radio2 is selected.
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Omg Thank you so much @KalpeshPatel!

Comment: Em ... is it also possible to know how to do it so not all can be clicked at the same time?

Comment: Embed all your `RadioButton` inside `RadioGroup`.

Comment: Yes thank you. Did figure it out by "chance" :D :D but thank you!